# Git: "get_tz_offset" is not exported by the Git module

Tags: git, cvs, cvsimport

Attempting to convert an old CVS repository into a git repo while keeping all the git history. However, I'm encountering the following error when I run the following command inside of my old CVS project:

> git cvsimport -C "Directory of where I want to save to" "CVS Module"
>
> "get_tz_offset" is not exported by the Git module
> Can't continue after import errors at /usr/libexc/git-core/git-cvsimport line 31
> BEGIN failed -- compilation aborted at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-cvsimport line 31

What line 31 consists of:

> vim /usr/libexec/git-core/git-cvsimport
>
> 31: use Git gw(get_tz_offset)

I'm running red hat 7.4 git version 2.18.0 with cvs version 1.11.23

Any suggestions? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I was originally running off a git version 1.X version, but git cvsimport was not introduced until later.

Comment: You're probably using the system `Git` Perl module from the old 1.x  version with with your new version of Git.  Either specify `PERL5LIB` or use the Git version from Software Collections.